# How to insert online video programmatically in PowerPoint from an add-in

Tags: powerpoint, ms-office, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

I am developing a PowerPoint add-in using Office JS API. The end game is to have a configurable video object on a slide that would play during the presentation. I started it as a Content add-in, but I am seeing multiple issues and limitations with that. I am stuck and starting to think of alternative solutions. One that I imagine is to configure and prepare the video using the Task Pane add-in, then insert it into the slide as an "Online Video" object. Though I cannot find anything in the API regarding that object. Apparently, video is not a supported content type either. Is there any other way to achieve what I need? Thanks!